# React Router, 2 routes with similar urls

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have the following 2 routes:

```
<RouteEx path="/:id" component={Page2} />
<RouteEx path="/imprint" component={Imprint} />
```

Every time I click on imprint to navigate to my imprint page, I get an error in my console from Page2 component. How do I prevent calling Page2 when I want to navigate to Imprint page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Route Matching" section of the [React-Router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/basic-components) provides some tools for dealing with routes that can both serve as matches to the address text. The first is `<Switch>`, which makes it so that only one route--the first match, even if there are many--responds to the route match. Another is the `exact` property, which guarantees that a route won't be flexibly interpreted. In your case, you might use them both (though I think the `exact` tag may not be necessary in your case):

```
<Switch>
  <RouteEx exact path="/imprint" component={Imprint} />
  <RouteEx path="/:id" component={Page2} /> 
</Switch>
```

In this configuration, if the route matches `'/imprint'`, it will *not* trigger the `'/:id'` route. This will work even if the `id` is a string. (Naturally, you'd have to make sure that you never encounter the case `id === 'imprint'`.)

Comment: Thanks! This seems a much cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

If id is a number, then you can try using Regex :

```
    <RouteEx exact path="/:id(\d+)" component={Page2}/>
    <RouteEx exact path="/imprint" component={Imprint}/>
```

Comment: No problem @SanjnaMalpani